# V-model is updating unreferenced state data

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuex

I am trying to copy an object in the vuex store to a local component object so that I can change it locally and not modify the store state object. However, when I associate the local object with a textarea v-model, it changes the store state data even though it is not directly referenced. I am not sure how this is happening or even possible.

```
<v-textarea v-model="currentObj.poltxt" solo light></v-textarea>

  watch: { //watch for current UID changes
    "$store.state.currentUID"(nv) {
      //Clearing the local temporary object
      this.currentObj = {};
      //Moving the store state data into the local object
      this.currentObj = this.$store.state.docuMaster[this.$store.state.currentUID];
    }
  }
```

The watch function is executing and when I console log *this.$store.state.docuMaster[this.$store.state.currentUID]* I can see that v-model is directly updating it even though its referencing *currentObj*. Any idea why this is happening? The text box is not referencing the store in any other place in code.

Comment: is `this.$store.state.docuMaster[this.$store.state.currentUID]` an object or a nested object?

Comment: docuMaster itself is a nested object.

Comment: that's right, what about the currentId entry inside `docuMaster`, is that again a nested object. Anyways check my solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `this.$store.state.docuMaster[this.$store.state.currentUID]` is not a nested object then try using

```
//Moving the store state data into the local object
      this.currentObj = Object.assign({}, this.$store.state.docuMaster[this.$store.state.currentUID]);
```

If `this.$store.state.docuMaster[this.$store.state.currentUID])` is a nested object then you got to do deep clone

```
this.currentObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.state.docuMaster[this.$store.state.currentUID]));
```

Note:
Nested object in the sense I mean

```
docuMaster: {
 UID: {
  ...
   xyz: {}
 },
....
}
```

Not a nested obj means

```
docuMaster: {
 UID: {
  //no inner objects
 },
....
}
```

Comment: Object.assign appears to be working. Thank you! Any idea why this happens? Why would v-model effect docuMaster when it never references it?

Comment: Great! if that helped, pls do consider giving an upvote and accepting the answer

Comment: Thats happening becoz when you directly assign it, it gets copied with reference. So even though its stored in a different variable, it still shares the same reference hence when changed in one place will reflect the other

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon. It worked for copying it, but now v-model cannot change currentObj. The object is staying static and the text area will not change it.

Comment: yes becoz if your using it in v-model, the updation should happen only through v-model but in our case, updation might happen from two ways either from v-model or through watch therefore there is a conflict

Comment: I believe I have it worked now. currentObj wasn't updating because I had it defined as basically empty in data(){return{}}. I added a property to it and now it works. Thanks again.

Comment: Just to updated this for future reference: I ended up having to use the json method because object.assign was still passing a reference that was being used for checklist v-model's. The json method appears to break any references.

Comment: Maybe then yours is multi-level obj, hence you need to go with json method for deep clone